# Add background image in netsuite advanced pdf

Tags: netsuite

I am trying change the opacity of a background image added on the advanced pdf template print.The background image gets applied but i cannot change opacity as i am unable to apply css...

```
 body{
        background-image:url("https://system.eu2.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=11&amp;c=4667350&amp;h=158ccc0fb10e81fb87dc");
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Could you please try this
BACKGROUND-MACRO attribute
Type:   macro
Inherited:  no
Used By:    body, pbr and the #page CSS elements
Default:    none
See:    footer header rotate
The background-macro attribute specifies a macro to apply to each page first before the content is applied. More flexible than header and footer, the macro is effectively a DIV covering the whole page (including the header and footer), and can be used to add anything from watermarks to hole-punch guides.

This places a "Confidential" stamp on each page, rotated at 45% counter-clockwise


 <head>
<macrolist>
  <macro id="watermark">
    <p rotate="-45" font-size="48pt">
      Confidential
    </p>
  </macro>
</macrolist>
</head>
<body background-macro="watermark">
<p><!--Content--></p>
</body>
```